# Connection parameters in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, connection, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

How to establish connection to remote DB in Oracle SQL Developer if there only login, password and DB name are available?

Connection is successful in SQLPlus and PL/SQL Dev, but SQL Developer require **hostname and port**, but I don't know them.

Comment: How are you connecting in SQL Plus? Are you using a TNS entry to connect. If so check your tnsnames.ora for the port and hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can check tnsnames in %ORACLE_HOME%\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora

If there is nothing helpful there - then connect in SQLPlus and do
 `select host_name from v$instance`.

Port is almost always is 1521, but I don't know where to get it in the open session. If you can't connect on port 1521 - then call your admin and ask what made him change his heart.

Answer (score 0):

If you have TNS set up for connections on your system then go to the %ORACLE_HOME%\Network\Admin directory. In there you will find your tnsnames.ora file in which you will get the hostname and port of the remote DB you are trying to connect from.

Either that or use TNS to connect to the remote DB in SQL Developer. It is possible as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

You can get get the hostname with:

```
SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name from dual;
```

or the ip_adress with:

```
SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_adress from dual;
```

For port you can try 1521 if you use TNS.